# Edit Form React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I´m making an edit form with React js. I have multiple components in the form. In one of the son components, I pass all the changes that I`ve done to a hook in the main component to do the changes in firebase.

Father Component

```
const [changes, setChanges] = useState({});
const updateGenData = (genData) => {
    setChanges(genData);  
  }
```

Son Component(I take all the info from the father, via props)

```
const UpdateProfileGenData = (props) => {

 const [values, setValues] = useState({});
 const [changes, setChanges] = useState({});

 useEffect(() => {
    setValues(props);
 },[props]); 

 const {field1, field2, field3} = values;

 useEffect(() => {
    props.updateGenData(changes);
},[changes]); 

  const handleChange= e => {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
         setChanges({
          ...changes,
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }) 
    }
return (

<input type="text" name="field1" value={field1} onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" name="field2" value={field2} onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" name="field3" value={field3} onChange={handleChange}/>

);
}
export default UpdateProfileGenData;
```

When I pass the values ​​from the child component to the parent it doesn't allow me to edit the child form . I can´t change any field.

Any suggestions??

Regards

Comment: How do you pass the props to your `UpdateProfileGenData` component? Can you provide a codesandbox or a like for this?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `useEffect` so often? The problem may be that you often use `useEffect` and somewhere you overwrite the data correctly.
Can be made easier:

Father Component

```
const [changes, setChanges] = useState({});
const updateGenData = (genData) => setChanges({...changes, ...genData});
```

Son Component

```
const UpdateProfileGenData = ({field1, field2, field3, updateGenData}) => {

  const handleChange= e => updateGenData({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });

return (

<input type="text" name="field1" value={field1} onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" name="field2" value={field2} onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" name="field3" value={field3} onChange={handleChange}/>

);
}
export default UpdateProfileGenData;
```